# Publish Html Report from multiple folders under singe Report Name - Jenkins, HTML Publisher

Tags: jenkins, plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have multiple code coverage reports in multiple folders under a singe name index.html , I need to Publish all the report Under a single name Called coverage report. Inside that all the index.html file should come.

The Thing I am looking to achieve is something like given below mentioning multiple folders in report directory.

```
publishHTML (target : [allowMissing: false,
alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true,
keepAll: true,
reportDir: 'folder1/target, folder2/target, folder3/target',
reportFiles: 'index.html',
reportName: 'Coverage Report',
reportTitles: 'The Report'])
```

Note: While Building the project all the coverage report will be present in the target folder called index.html and I need to get that reports published in jenkins uner the Coverage Report Name

Could you please suggest a way to achieve the above scenario..

Comment: Were you able to achieve this